# I like SpringBoot ,It can build rest service application easily. But I also need to make more config in application.xml

Tags: spring

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication sa = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        sa.run();

    }
```

How can I add applicaiton.xml into the SpringApplication ?? And How can I get ApplicationContext through SpringApplication??

I know how to load config in a standalone application:

```
public App () {
         ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application.xml") ;
         ts = (TestService)ctx.getBean("TestService");
    }
```

I want to combine the application.xml and SpringBoot..... Need Help~!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: JakubK gave a right answer and I have solved the issue. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `@ImportResource` annotation on your `@Configuration` class:

```
@ImportResource("classpath:application.xml")
```